# Element wise inversion in Eigen Matrix

Tags: c++, matrix, eigen, eigen3

Is there a function/s for doing elementwise inversion of an Eigen Matrix

```
#include <eigen3/Eigen/Dense>

const auto mat = Eigen::MatrixXd::Constant(3, 3, 5);
std::cout << mat;

5 5 5
5 5 5
5 5 5
```

And my expected result is this:

```
1/5 1/5 1/5
1/5 1/5 1/5
1/5 1/5 1/5
```

Is there any other way to do this apart from using a for-loop? (Also, will using a for loop on eigen matrix for scalar operations be slower as compared to matrix operations)

Comment: Unrelated, but be aware of the pitfalls when using `auto` with Eigen (https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/TopicPitfalls.html). In your case `const auto mat` will not be an actual matrix object, but a meta-object which mostly behaves like a matrix object (this may or may not be what you want).

Comment: Hey thanks for letting me know. I came across this issue few minutes ago! Removing the auto solves the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this issue. Just putting here in case anyone else comes across this issue

```
mat.cwiseInverse()
```

[Link to all co-efficient wise functions for eigen](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__CoeffwiseMathFunctions.html)